# How do I merge multiple lists using JSON ref?

Tags: json, yaml, json-ref

I have the following YAML

```
- name: Core
  description: Core functionality
- name: Artifact
  description: Artifact management

# - $ref: "v1/publications.yml#/tags/"
```

v1/publications.yml has

```
tags:
  - name: Publication
    description: |
      This defines the publication API.
```

I sort of want the result to be
I have the following YAML

```
- name: Core
  description: Core functionality
- name: Artifact
  description: Artifact management
- name: Publication
  description: |
    This defines the publication API.

# - $ref: "v1/publications.yml#/tags/"
```

I can do it one at a time like this...

```
- name: Core
  description: Core functionality
- name: Artifact
  description: Artifact management
- $ref: "v1/publications.yml#/tags/0"
```

But I want it to add multiple without updating my source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the technologies you tagged. `$ref` is exactly that, a reference to an external subtree. You need sequence concatenation, which is something neither [json-ref](/questions/tagged/json-ref) nor plain YAML or JSON provide.

You may be able to do this using some templating technology, which many YAML-based utilities provide. If you are in control of the loading code, you can also implement custom tags to do something like

```yaml
- name: Core
  description: Core functionality
- name: Artifact
  description: Artifact management
- !append {$ref: "v1/publications.yml#/tags"}
```